# Merge and order two streams using Kotlin flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have two streams where each stream has a different set of values and a different amount:

```
runBlocking {
    val flowA = flow {
        mutableListOf<Int>(0, 4, 9).forEach {
            emit(it)
        }
    }

    val flowB = flow {
        mutableListOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8).forEach {
            emit(it)
        }
    }

    merge(flowA, flowB).collect{
        Log.i(TAG, it.toString())
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use Kotlin's Flow to merge these two streams so that the result is sorted? So the collected values should end up being:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

The values in each stream is already sorted. I just need to merge them. One very important thing however. I don't want to sort AFTER all the values have been collected. The sorting must be done as each value is emitted. My sample above is over simplified. In the real app, the source for each flow contains large arrays for each item. Waiting for all the values to be collected and then sorting is unacceptable as this would require a large amount of memory. But the basic concept for simple integer values should work for more complex data types as well.

Maybe the filter operator is what I need but that isn't clear as I have little experience with flows.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this using the built-in flow operators, but you should certainly be able to implement your own. You can use `channelFlow` for that purpose. This is a versatile way to build a flow that gives us a coroutine scope to work in, and lets us emit items by sending to a channel.

```kotlin
fun <T> mergeOrdered(flowA: Flow<T>, flowB: Flow<T>) = channelFlow {
    val channelA = flowA.produceIn(this)
    val channelB = flowB.produceIn(this)
    var a = channelA.receive()
    var b = channelB.receive()
    while (isActive) {
        if (a < b) {
            send(a)
            a = channelA.receive()
        } else {
            send(b)
            b = channelB.receive()
        }
    }
}
```

This simple example doesn't handle what happens when `flowA` and `flowB` run out of elements, but that should be easy enough to add.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is the first time I've used Flow.

Even though the streams are "already sorted", it seems you cannot control the timing the elements will arrive from the two streams. So, you will only be able to get an ordered list by collecting all the elements, then sorting them.

This worked for me:

```
val sortedResults = flowA
    .onCompletion { emitAll(flowB) }
    .toCollection(mutableListOf())
    .sorted()

println(sortedResults)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Ah, the question was edited. If you don't want to sort at the end, the only other way is to keep the list sorted every time an element is added. You'd still need to buffer the entire thing otherwise how would you know, for example, whether the last element comes at the end, or goes somewhere else?

Comment: I wonder if you can selectively take from each flow depending on the next value? Sorry, speculating now. Still sounds like you'd need a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `combine` operator to get value from two or more `flows` and then a `flatMapLatest` operator like this:

```
val desiredFlow = combine(getFlowA(),getFlowB()) { a, b ->

    val arr = IntArray(a.size + b.size)

    var i = 0
    var j = 0
    var k = 0

    while (i < a.size && j < b.size)
        arr[k++] = if (a[i] < b[j]) a[i++] else b[j++]

    while (i < a.size)
        arr[k++] = a[i++]

    while (j < b.size)
        arr[k++] = b[j++]

    arr

}.flatMapLatest { result ->

    flow {

        emit(result.toMutableList())
    }
}

fun getFlowA(): Flow<MutableList<Int>> {

    return flow {

        emit(mutableListOf<Int>(0,4,9))
    }
}

fun getFlowB(): Flow<MutableList<Int>> {

    return flow {

        emit(mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
    }
}
```

I'm from the `Android dev` world and not expert with `Flows` so kindly pardon me if isn't what you expected, but this produces the final output as:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Accumulating items in arrays is not good. While the simple sample I posted is just integers, the real app has objects with very large arrays and thousands of items. This solution would not be practical for that.

Comment: Ok, do tell if you find an optimised way of achieving this result, would like to know about it :)

Answer (score 0):

After going through the question, I have two ideas either using a flatten merge or using a delay.

The first idea looks something like this.

```
        runBlocking {
            val flowA = flow {
                mutableListOf<Int>(0, 4, 9).forEach {
                    emit(it)
                }
            }

            val flowB = flow {
                mutableListOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8).forEach {
                    emit(it)
                }
            }

          val newList = mutableListOf<Int>()


            val a = flowOf(flowA, flowB).flattenMerge().collect { value ->
                when {
                    newList.isEmpty() -> newList.add(value)
                    newList.last() <= value -> newList.add(value)

                    newList.last() > value -> {
                        //sorting values as they arrive
                        val i = newList.lastIndex
                        newList.add(value)
                        val newValue = newList[i]
                        newList[i] = newList[i + 1]
                        newList[i + 1] = newValue
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, newList.toString())
        }
```

In the second one, add appropriate delays to your first 2 flows.

PS:-
*Android Studio gives a warning while using flattenMerge.*
*This declaration is in a preview state and can be changed in a backwards-incompatible manner with a best-effort migration. Its usage should be marked with '@kotlinx.coroutines.FlowPreview' or '@OptIn(kotlinx.coroutines.FlowPreview::class)' if you accept the drawback of relying on preview API*